# Xamarin Android Emulator Phone Number

Tags: xamarin

I am using Xamarin and Android Emulator. I want to write a simple app which grabs the user's phone number. I am using

```
            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;

            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);

            var Number = mTelephonyMgr.Line1Number;
```

But it does not work. The app crashes at 2nd line. My questions are,

- Do the emulator has any phone number?
- How to get it working on emulator, and then on actual device?

This is the exception I get

```
+       ex  {Java.Lang.SecurityException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.SecurityException' was thrown.
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:178 
  at Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager.get_Line1Number () [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-10/src/generated/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager.cs:377 
  at UnwantedNumbers.MainActivity.<OnCreate>b__0 (System.Object param0, System.EventArgs param1) [0x00013] in e:\data\trunk\Yuan Miao\Coding Examples\Mobile App\UnwantedNumbers\UnwantedNumbers\MainActivity.cs:39 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10037 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo$Stub$Proxy.getLine1Number(IPhoneSubInfo.java:231)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getLine1Number(TelephonyManager.java:624)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
}   Java.Lang.SecurityException
```

Comment: Do you need a specific Android permission for that in the manifest?

Comment: It's a good idea to include the exception that happens. That way it's easier to identify why exactly the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

It says it in you exception `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`. Add that permission to your manifest and you should be good to go...